# mavenCentral() plugins download failed while gradle project sync in android studio

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-plugin

I am new to Android Studio. First time I have started the android studio and the gradle project sync is failing continuously because some files are failing to download.
I have again tried but the mavenCetral repositories are failing to download which are:

1. 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.9.0/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.9.0-gradle80.jar'
2. 'https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.9.0/kotlin-compiler-embeddable-1.9.0.jar'

**Android Studio Version: ** 2022.3.1 "Giraffe"

I have tried several ways to solve this problem but anything doesnt work for me

I have also tried to manually download those files and paste in the gradle folder but it also doesnt work.

--> Even, the layout editor of android studio is not started, it is showing "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not properly work
--> First, there was issue with around 15-16 files. but, now, only 2 files are remaining to download.

Please, anyone help.

Attached all the releated screenshots

[Download error in gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKoEg.png)

[Download info in gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOsug.png)

[settings.gradle.kts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbqsT.png)

[build.gradle.kts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rHrT.png)

What I tried:

1. I have checked my proxi settings, they are as per the most of articles
2. Tried several time: File -> Sync project with gradle files
3. File -> Invalidate caches
4. Reload gradle project
5. File -> Project Structure -> suggestions (Updating any recommended files)
6. Restarting the laptop and also android studio

Also, my network speed is good. (I have also manually downloaded the several files)

What I am expecting:
How to download those two files and sync the project with gradle